# How to visualize a certain point on an image using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, drawing, emgucv

I loaded an image and processed it to detect certain shapes on the image, now i want to detect the centers of the objects and draw a line through the longest part of the image
it is supposed to look something like this (very bad edit i made in paint to get my point across) the idea is always to find the center and then draw the longest possible line through the object and center. Currently I am still at the point of detecting the centers,
I have this code

```
`public PointF[] FindCenters(VectorOfPoint contour)
        {
            // Create a Moments object to calculate the moments of the contour
            Moments moments = CvInvoke.Moments(contour, false);

            // Calculate the center of the contour using the moments
            float centerX = (float)(moments.M10 / moments.M00);
            float centerY = (float)(moments.M01 / moments.M00);

            // Return the center coordinates as a PointF array
            return new PointF[] { new PointF(centerX, centerY) };
```

and now i want to visualize the centers to just verify if the code worked, how could i implement that?
Thank you!

[four objects with the centers marked and vertical lines drawn through the centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZspD5.png)

Comment: I would draw a mark on the images at that position.

Comment: that would be my suggestion as well. I hope the question isn't "how do I draw on a picture". please take the [tour] and review [ask]